# Как в logstash обработать строки разного формата

Tags: filter, logstash, grok

Имеется лог HCL Unica вида:

```
06/07/2023 19:55:40.784 (27801, T = 2901669632) [I] [TABLE ACC] UA_SYSTEM_TABLES: Statement successful; 0 records affected. [sdbtacc:3148]
06/07/2023 19:55:41.007 (27801, T = 2901669632) [I] [GENERAL]   SESSION_SAVE bla-bla-bla
06/07/2023 19:55:42.514 (27801, T = 2901669632) [I] [INTERFACE] Connection broken at 60984
```

Как видно, первые 5 полей однородны и укладываются в стандартный парсинг.
Однако, начиная с 6 поля начинаются ветвления: в одной строке это UA_SYSTEM_TABLES, в другой — SESSION_SAVE, в третьей — начинается сам текст лога.

Собственно, задача состоит в том, чтобы корректно вытащить события вида SESSION_SAVE в отдельное поле.

С паттерном вида:

```
%{CUSTOMTIME:logdate}%{SPACE}\(%{GREEDYDATA:pid}\)%{SPACE}\[%{GREEDYDATA:loglevel}\]%{SPACE}\[%{DATA:category}\]%{SPACE}\[%{DATA:processname}\]%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:logtext}
```

Нормально парсятся строки, где сразу за пятым полем ([GENERAL],[INTERFACE] и т.д.) идет текст лога. Но в этом случае и нужное нам событие SESSION_SAVE попадает в logtext.

Подозреваю, что вопрос решается добавлением условий в фильтр logstash, но пока не могу понять, каких именно.

Спасибо.